# How to return several items from a Powershell function

Tags: powershell

In a script I have several functions that need to *break down an [SVN external definition](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)*. These can either be `<url> <path>`, `-r<rev> <url> <path>`, or `-r <rev> <url> <path>`, and the mechanics I came up with to extract the data is more than just two lines, so I want to put this into a separate function.

But when I do so, I end up with three variables containing the relevant data which are local to the function, and I see no way to get all three of them them to the caller.

In a proper programming language I would return a compound type containing all three values, but I don't see how to do that in Powershell. Of course, I could split this into three separate functions, but then I am back at violating the [DRY rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

So what can I do here in Powershell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return an array of `[string]` and then let the caller split it or return a [custom object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh750381.aspx) and always the caller do the split.

Comment: Oh, that custom object thing looks exactly like what I need!

Comment: An example is missing here, which would be useful.

Comment: example here: https://www.byteinthesky.com/powershell/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-function/

Answer (score 104):

I agree with @Christian, and I add another solution.

**First** you can return using an array explicitly or implicitly:

1. explicitly

   ```
   function ExplicitArray ()
   {
     $myArray = @()

     $myArray += 12
     $myArray += "Blue"

     return ,$myArray
   }

   Clear-Host
   $a = ExplicitArray
   Write-Host "values from ExplicitArray are $($a[0]) and $($a[1])"
   ```
2. implicitly

   ```
   function ImplicitArray ()
   {
     Write-Output 12

     Write-Output "Blue"
     return "green"
   }

   $b = ImplicitArray
   Write-Host "values from ImplicitArray are $($b[0]), $($b[1]) and $($b[2])"
   ```

**Second** you can return a custom object:

1. Short form

   ```
   function ReturnObject ()
   {
     $value = "" | Select-Object -Property number,color
     $value.Number = 12
     $value.color = "blue"
     return $value
   }
   $c = ReturnObject
   Write-Host "values from ReturnObject are $($c.number) and $($c.color)"
   ```
2. School form

   ```
   function SchoolReturnObject ()
   {
     $value = New-Object PsObject -Property @{color="blue" ; number="12"}
     Add-Member -InputObject $value –MemberType NoteProperty –Name "Verb" –value "eat"
     return $value
   }
   $d = SchoolReturnObject
   Write-Host "values from SchoolReturnObject are $($d.number), $($d.color) and $($d.Verb)"
   ```

**Third** using argument by reference:

```
function addition ([int]$x, [int]$y, [ref]$R)
{
 $Res = $x + $y
 $R.value = $Res
}

$O1 = 1
$O2 = 2
$O3 = 0
addition $O1 $O2 ([ref]$O3)
Write-Host "values from addition $o1 and $o2 is $o3"
```

Comment: Ah, you can pass arguments by reference! I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Note that it isn't necessary to use the `return` statements in the examples above.  `return` in PowerShell is typically only used to alter the normal exit point from a function.

Comment: This is your point of view, I respect it. My point of view is that `return $value` make the function code more readable, moreover in my code I quite never use the Write-Output in a function. I exists old rules about structured programmation, that I try to apply

Comment: @JPBlanc: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. I have accepted the other answer, thouqh, because Christian was first, and I ended up doing what he suggested (using a custom object).

Comment: Can anyone explain why you need the comma in `return ,$myArray`. Coming from languages other than PowerShell I don't see why that comma is needed (although through testing I agree it is!)

Comment: This is a way to return an array, even if `$myArray` is a value or an array with a single value, that return can evluate as a single value.

Comment: I learned `pascal` with `ref` and `value` parameters. Is this still useful, as seen in the 3rd example? A function that changes a paramter var and the var change is applied outside the function without the need for $var='new'.

Comment: @Tino This is not exactly the same usage as Pascal, but yes it's a way to modify original var from inside the function.

Comment: My favorite is solution #2 for clarity and code readability.

Answer (score 44):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but isn't this just as simple as returning a list of variables, and the caller simply assigns each to a variable.
That is

```
> function test () {return @('a','c'),'b'}
> $a,$b = test
```

$a will be an array, and $b the letter 'b'

```
> $a 
a
c
> $b
b
```

Comment: Underrated answer. This is definitely the cleanest solution.