# How to return a reference value with a method from an extended Powershell object?

Tags: powershell-5.0

I'm trying to extend a Powershell object with a method that

1. **returns** a true or false to indicate success
2. outputs a value by reference (`[ref]`)

I have in my **module** `MyExtensions.psm1`.

```powershell
Update-TypeData -TypeName [MyType] -MemberType ScriptMethod -memberName TryGetValue -force -value `
{
    param(
        $myInput,
        [ref]$myOutput
    )

    try
    {
        # do something with $myInput
        $myOutput = …
        return $true
    }
    catch
    {
        return $false
    }

}
```

The goal is to be able to write in a script or in another module:

```powershell
Import-Module MyExtensions
$myInput = …
$value = $null
if($myTypeItem.TryGetValue($myInput, $value)
{
  # I know that the $value is good
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using argument by reference (you  just miss `$myOutput.Value =""`)

```
function addition ([int]$x, [int]$y, [ref]$R)
{
 $Res = $x + $y
 $R.value = $Res
}

$O1 = 1
$O2 = 2
$O3 = 0
addition $O1 $O2 ([ref]$O3)
Write-Host "values from addition $o1 and $o2 is $o3"
```

A more comple answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12621314/608772).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So all I had missing was `$myOutput.value = …` in `MyExtensions.psm1` and the call should be `if($myTypeItem.TryGetValue($myInput, [ref]$value)`.