# Powershell - pass function results to other parts of the script

Tags: powershell, variables

New to Powershell.

I have a Powershell script that has a DO UNTIL loop.  Inside that loop I call 2 functions.  Based on the results of the functions determine if I can continue the script.  My issue seems to be passing the result of the function back into the DO UNTIL loop for the loop to continue.

Here is the general idea:

```
Function MyFunction1
{
(Stuff happens here)
    IF($Good -eq "Yes"){
            Return 1
    }Else{
            Return 0
    }
}


Function MyFunction2
{
(Other stuff happens here)
    IF($ReallyGood -eq "Yes"){
            Return 1
    }Else{
            Return 0
    }
}

DO{
    $a = MyFunction1
    IF($a -eq 1){
      $b = MyFunction2
            IF($b -eq 1){
                        $endscript = "Yes"
                        }ELSE{
                        $endscript = "No"
                        }
    }Else{
    $endscript = "No"
    }   
}UNTIL(
$endscript -eq "Yes")
```

Comment: Aside from the missing close paren on the last line, this runs fine on my machine. What's your expected output?

Comment: During the function more variables are established and their values are also returned.

Comment: Beware that PowerShell might return more than just the expression following `return`. Can you show what really goes on under `(Stuff happens here)`?

Comment: The full script is over 1000 lines but I think I figured it out from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620375/how-to-return-several-items-from-a-powershell-function

Answer (score 1):

Using this question: [How to return several items from a Powershell function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620375/how-to-return-several-items-from-a-powershell-function)

I went with creating a variable within the function and setting the property to a number.  Then assigning that variable a number.  Finally, in the IF statement, I can reference that variable property.

```
Function MyFunction1
{
(Stuff happens here)

    $fun1_value = "" | Select-Object -Property number

    IF($Good -eq "Yes"){
            $fun1_value = 1
            Return $fun1_value
    }Else{
            $fun1_value = 0
            Return $fun1_value
    }
}


Function MyFunction2
{
(Other stuff happens here)

    $fun2_value = "" | Select-Object -Property number

    IF($ReallyGood -eq "Yes"){
            $fun2_value = 1
            Return $fun2_value
    }Else{
            $fun2_value = 0
            Return $fun2_value
    }
}

DO{
    $fun1 = MyFunction1
    IF($fun1.number -eq 1){
      $fun2 = MyFunction2
            IF($fun2.number -eq 1){
                        $endscript = "Yes"
                        }ELSE{
                        $endscript = "No"
                        }
    }Else{
    $endscript = "No"
    }   
}UNTIL(
$endscript -eq "Yes")
```

Comment: Sorry, but  `$fun1_value = 1`  is going to overwrite `$fun1_value` created by `$fun1_value = "" | Select-Object -Property number` you should write : `$fun1_value.number=1`